# What are Dummy fastqs?

Tags: ngs, linux, cancer

I had to do a file transfer for in our system to run from fastqs and I came across the term "dummy fastq", not sure what exactly it means and what is the purpose of it in the workflow. Can someone answer?

Answer (score 2):

Probably some made-up data solely for the sake of testing a workflow but actually impossible to know what random files are sitting on your servers.